# Type equivalence in Pascal-like languages

Tags: types, pascal, modula-2, oberon

The Oberon-2 language report "The Programming Language Oberon–2" has the following definition in appendix A:

> Two variables *a* and *b* with types *T*<sub>*a*</sub> and *T*<sub>*b*</sub> are of the *same type* if
>
> 1. *T*<sub>*a*</sub> and *T*<sub>*b*</sub> are both denoted by the same type identifier, or
> 2. *T*<sub>*a*</sub> is declared to equal *T*<sub>*b*</sub> in a type declaration of the form *T*<sub>*a*</sub> = *T*<sub>*b*</sub>, or
> 3. *a* and *b* appear in the same identifier list in a variable, record field, or formal parameter declaration and are not open arrays.

Given the type declarations

```
Ta = INTEGER
Tb = INTEGER
Tc = Tb
```

paragraph two in the above definition suggests that

- *Ta* and *Tb* are different types (no declaration of *Ta* = *Tb*),
- *Ta* and *Tc* are different types (no declaration of *Ta* = *Tc*) and
- *Tc* and INTEGER are different types (no declaration of *Tc* = INTEGER).

Is this a correct interpretation of *same type* in Oberon-2? As far as I understand, Oberon-2 is quite strict when it comes to name equivalence, and in this context the interpretation actually makes sense. What about Standard Pascal and ISO Modula-2?

Comment: In Pascal, INTEGER is a predefined type identifier, so Ta, Tb, and Tc would all be the same type. My guess is that the same is true for Oberon-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation of *same type* in the question follows what is called *strict name equivalence*. In Ada, for instance, this feature is supported through *derived types*. Under strict name equivalence each type declaration introduces a distinct type. Pascal, Modula-2 and Oberon, however, all use *non-strict name equivalence*. This means that for a type identifier *T*<sub>*a*</sub>, the declarations *T*<sub>*b*</sub> = *T*<sub>*a*</sub> and *T*<sub>*c*</sub> = *T*<sub>*a*</sub> make *T*<sub>*b*</sub> and *T*<sub>*c*</sub> equivalent.